# How programically do what Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer is doing?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

there is a tutorial in Microsoft docs that you can see here:
[Tutorial: Build your first pipeline to transform data using Hadoop cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline)

in "Prerequisites" section, in step 6, they wrote "Use tools such as Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer".

the question is, can I use some other tools? especially, is it possible to use scripting languages like Python directly?
I need to do all these 7 steps dynamically, using something like Azure Function Apps. do you know is it possible and if it is, from where I should start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is **YES**. But again, you have not shared details on what functionality are you looking for specifically.

What you can do is call the REST API endpoints for the corresponding service.

Depending on whether you are using Blobs or Table or Queues, there are specific API's that you can call.

[Azure Storage Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/azure-storage-services-rest-api-reference)

- [Blob service REST API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api)
- [Queue Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/queue-service-rest-api)
- [Table Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api)
- [File Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api)

Taking Blobs as example, we have API's to upload content using **PUT** method. See this for more details: [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob)

Similarly, you have API's for reading containers, listing containers etc.

There is also some samples on working with Azure Storage in Python on Github. See this: [Azure-Samples/storage-python-getting-started](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-python-getting-started)

HTH